# Creating a 3D plot from a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

Ok, so I feel like there should be an easy way to create a 3-dimensional scatter plot using matplotlib. I have a 3D numpy array (`dset`) with 0's where I don't want a point and 1's where I do, basically to plot it now I have to step through three `for:` loops as such:

```
for i in range(30):
    for x in range(60):
        for y in range(60):
            if dset[i, x, y] == 1:
                ax.scatter(x, y, -i, zdir='z', c= 'red')
```

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this more efficiently? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have a `dset` like that, and you want to just get the `1` values, you could use `nonzero`, which "returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension of `a`, containing the indices of the non-zero elements in that dimension.".

For example, we can make a simple 3d array:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.random.seed(29)
>>> d = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, size=(3,3,3))
>>> d
array([[[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]])
```

and find where the nonzero elements are located:

```
>>> d.nonzero()
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]))
>>> z,x,y = d.nonzero()
```

If we wanted a more complicated cut, we could have done something like `(d > 3.4).nonzero()` or something, as True has an integer value of 1 and counts as nonzero.

Finally, we plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, -z, zdir='z', c= 'red')
plt.savefig("demo.png")
```

giving

[image: demo 3d image]

Comment: Beautiful. I have a a question about the `(d > 3.4).nonzero()` part though, would that return just the places where d has a value greater than 3.4?

Comment: @pter: exactly right.  `(d > 3.4)` gives a boolean array the same shape as `d` with `True` where the entry is > 3.4 and `False` elsewhere.

Comment: sweet I didnt know about this (dont usually need 3d plots... but if i do this will be awesome!) thanks DSM

Comment: Is there a way to draw surface plots in matplotlib using 3d numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid using the `nonzero` option (for example, if you had a 3D numpy array whose values were supposed to be the color values of the data points), you could do what you do, but save some lines of code by using `ndenumerate`.

Your example might become:

```
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(dset):
    if x == 1:
        ax.scatter(*index, c = 'red')
```

I guess the point is just that you dont need to have nested for loops to iterate through multidimensional numpy arrays.