# 3D array of numbers output as 2D isometric image

Tags: arrays, 3d

I have a 3D array of numbers from 0 to 9 to represent objects in a space, where

0 - empty space,
1 - space boundary,
2 - item 1,
3 - item 2,
...

Is it possible to assign colours to each number and output these as part of a 2D isometric view (viewed from a certain angle) of a 3D objects? (with 0 being transparent)

I would like a 3D representation of the object i have described.

I understand there is a concept for RGB colours but that only serves to populate the array with 3 colours, which means i have to break down my array further?

sorry i am very new to CS in general with a background in mechanical engineering so i am trying to learn.

Comment: i have found that 3D scatter plot on Excel does the job quite well though it is essentially on a 2D plane.

Comment: http://www.doka.ch/Excel3Dscatterplot.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a plotting library like [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). You will only be able to draw simple shapes but that is enough for the problem you have.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414619/creating-a-3d-plot-from-a-3d-numpy-array) for an example of how you can plot a 3d array.

Matplotlib is a python library, if you are using a different language I'm sure it has a similar library available.