# How to Plot in 3D Principal Component Analysis Visualizations, using the fast PCA script from this answer

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, data-visualization, pca

I found [this fast script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933271/9550633) here in Stack Overflow for perform PCA with a given numpy array.

I don't know how to plot this in 3D, and also plot in 3D the Cumulative Explained Variances and the Number of Components. This fast script was perform with covariance method, and not with singular value decomposition, maybe that's the reason why I can't get my Cumulative Variances?

I tried to plotting with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414814/9550633), but it doesn't work.

This is the code and my output:

```
from numpy import array, dot, mean, std, empty, argsort
from numpy.linalg import eigh, solve
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show

def cov(X):
    """
    Covariance matrix
    note: specifically for mean-centered data
    note: numpy's `cov` uses N-1 as normalization
    """
    return dot(X.T, X) / X.shape[0]
    # N = data.shape[1]
    # C = empty((N, N))
    # for j in range(N):
    #   C[j, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, j])
    #   for k in range(j + 1, N):
    #       C[j, k] = C[k, j] = mean(data[:, j] * data[:, k])
    # return C

def pca(data, pc_count = None):
    """
    Principal component analysis using eigenvalues
    note: this mean-centers and auto-scales the data (in-place)
    """
    data -= mean(data, 0)
    data /= std(data, 0)
    C = cov(data)
    E, V = eigh(C)
    key = argsort(E)[::-1][:pc_count]
    E, V = E[key], V[:, key]
    U = dot(data, V)
    print(f'Eigen Values: {E}')
    print(f'Eigen Vectors: {V}')
    print(f'Key: {key}')
    print(f'U: {U}')
    print(f'shape: {U.shape}')
    return U, E, V

data = dftransformed.transpose() # df tranpose and convert to numpy

trans = pca(data, 3)[0]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = subplots(1, 2)
ax1.scatter(data[:50, 0], data[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax1.scatter(data[50:, 0], data[50:, 1], c = 'b')
ax2.scatter(trans[:50, 0], trans[:50, 1], c = 'r')
ax2.scatter(trans[50:, 0], trans[50:, 1], c = 'b')
show()
```

I understand the eigen values & eigen vectors, but I can't understand this key value, the user didn't comment this section of code in the answer, anyone knows what means each variable printed?

output:

```
Eigen Values: [126.30390621  68.48966957  26.03124927]
Eigen Vectors: [[-0.05998409  0.05852607 -0.03437937]
 [ 0.00807487  0.00157143 -0.12352761]
 [-0.00341751  0.03819162  0.08697668]
 ...
 [-0.0210582   0.06601974 -0.04013712]
 [-0.03558994  0.02953385  0.01885872]
 [-0.06728424 -0.04162485 -0.01508154]]
Key: [439 438 437]
U: [[-12.70954048   8.97405411  -2.79812235]
 [ -4.90853527   4.36517107   0.54129243]
 [ -2.49370123   0.48341147   7.26682759]
 [-16.07860635   6.16100749   5.81777637]
 [ -1.81893291   6.48443689  -5.8655646 ]
 [  9.03939039   2.64196391   4.22056618]
 [-14.71731064   9.19532016  -2.79275543]
 [  1.60998654   8.37866823   0.86207034]
 [ -4.4503797   10.12688097  -5.12453656]
 [ 12.16293556   2.2594413   -2.11730311]
 [-15.76505125   9.48537581  -2.73906772]
 [ -2.54289959   9.86768111  -4.84802992]
 [ -5.78214902   9.21901651  -8.13594627]
 [ -1.35428398   5.85550586   6.30553987]
 [ 12.87261987   0.96283606  -3.26982121]
 [ 24.57767477  -4.28214631   6.29510659]
 [  4.13941679   3.3688288    3.01194055]
 [ -2.98318764   1.32775227   7.62610929]
 [ -4.44461549  -1.49258339   1.39080386]
 [ -0.10590795  -0.3313904    8.46363066]
 [  6.05960739   1.03091753   5.10875657]
 [-21.27737352  -3.44453629   3.25115921]
 [ -1.1183025    0.55238687  10.75611405]
 [-10.6359291    7.58630341  -0.55088259]
 [  4.52557492  -8.05670864   2.23113833]
 [-11.07822559   1.50970501   4.66555889]
 [ -6.89542628 -19.24672805  -3.71322812]
 [ -0.57831362 -17.84956249  -5.52002876]
 [-12.70262277 -14.05542691  -2.72417438]
 [ -7.50263129 -15.83723295  -3.2635125 ]
 [ -7.52780216 -17.60790567  -2.00134852]
 [ -5.34422731 -17.29394266  -2.69261597]
 [  9.40597893   0.21140292   2.05522806]
 [ 12.12423431  -2.80281266   7.81182024]
 [ 19.51224195   4.7624575  -11.20523383]
 [ 22.38102384   0.82486072  -1.64716468]
 [ -8.60947699   4.12597477  -6.01885407]
 [  9.56268414   1.18190655  -5.44074124]
 [ 14.97675455   3.31666971  -3.30012109]
 [ 20.47530869  -1.95896058  -1.91238615]]
shape: (40, 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Key is just sorting index wrt eigenvalues and U is your dataset projected on the nth first PC.

Comment: There is an example in this kernel,  https://www.kaggle.com/zonnalobo/timeseries-segmentation-and-forecasting, how to pca results to 2-dimension and 3-dimension. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `trans = pca(data, 3)[0]` is the `U` data, since `[0]` selects the first index of the returned data, and `pca` returns `U, E, V`
- `ax2.scatter(trans[:50, 0], trans[:50, 1], c = 'r')` plots the first 50 rows of column 0 against the first 50 rows of column 1, and `ax2.scatter(trans[50:, 0], trans[50:, 1], c = 'b')` does the same for rows from 50 to the end. This from the sample data given in [this fast script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27933271/9550633), but your data only has `shape: (40, 3)` (e.g. only 40 rows of data).
- In order to plot `trans` as a 3d scatter plot, extract each of the 3 columns into a separate variable and plot as a scatter plot.

```py
# imports as shown in the linked answer
from numpy import array, dot, mean, std, empty, argsort
from numpy.linalg import eigh, solve
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show

# other imports
import numpy as np

# test data from linked answer (e.g. this fast script)
np.random.seed(365)  # makes data repeatable
data = array([randn(8) for k in range(150)])  # creates array with shape (150, 8)
data[:50, 2:4] += 5  # adds 5 to first 50 rows of columns 2:4
data[50:, 2:5] += 5  # adds 5 to to rows from 50 of columns 2:5

# function call
trans = pca(data, 3)[0]  # [0] gets U returned by pca(...)

# extract each column to a separate variable
x = trans[:, 0]  # all rows of column 0
y = trans[:, 1]  # all rows of column 1
z = trans[:, 2]  # all rows of column 2

# plot 3d scatter plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
```

[image]